# Mi código de validación en JavaScript no funciona ¿Cuál es el problema?

Tags: javascript, formularios, validación

Tengo un código de JavaScript para validar un formulario y, cuando se ejecuta, me funciona el primer if, pero después ya no funciona y me regresa `true`, y no quiere comprobar lo demás, ¿Qué le pasa?

```js
function val () {

 var user, full, mail, pass, rpas, num, expresion;
 user = document.getElementById('user').value;
 full = document.getElementById('FullName').value;
 mail = document.getElementById('email').value;
 pass = document.getElementById('password').value;
 rpas = document.getElementById('conf_password').value;

 expresion = /\w+@\w+\.+[a-z]/;
 num = /[a-z]/;

 if (user == "" || full == "" || mail == "" || pass == "" || rpas == ""){
  alert("Uno de los campos esta vacio, por favor rellenalo");
  return false;
 }else if (pass !== rpas){
  alert("Las contraseñas no son iguales");
  return false;
 }else if (user.length > 28 || user.length < 6 || user.length = 0){
  alert("Tu nombre de usuario tiene algun problema");
  return false;
 }else if (user.length < 6){
  alert("Tu nombre de usuario es muy corto");
  return false;
 }else if (pass.length < 8 || pass.length > 25){
  alert("Contraseña muy corta o muy larga");
  return false;
 }else if (mail.length < 9 || mail.length > 40){
  alert("Correo es muy corto o muy largo");
  return false;
 }else if (!expresion.test(mail)){
  alert("Formato de correo no valido o el campo esta vacio");
  return false;
 }else if (full.length < 5 || full.length > 30){
  alert("Nombre completo muy corto o muy largo");
  return false;
 }else{
  return true;
 }
}
```

```html
    <form role="form" name="registro" action="php/registro.php" method="post" onsubmit="return val(this)">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="user" class="text-color-black">Nombre de usuario</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user" name="user" placeholder="Nombre de usuario">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="FullName" class="text-color-black">Nombre Completo</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FullName" name="FullName" placeholder="Nombre completo">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="text-color-black">Correo Electronico</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo Electronico">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password" class="text-color-black">Contraseña</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="conf_password" class="text-color-black">Confirmar Contraseña</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="conf_password" name="conf_password" placeholder="Confirmar Contraseña">
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Registrar</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Todo el código para reproducir el escenario, buena primera pregunta :)

Comment: solo como referencia y si no lo hiciste, haz el [tour]. Bienvenido!

Answer (score 4):

Tienes un error de sintaxis en una de las líneas. Revisa esto:

```
}else if (user.length > 28 || user.length < 6 || user.length = 0){
```

y cámbialo por user.length == (operador de asignación vs operador de comparación). Saludos.

Comment: Ya realice el cambio y sigue solo verificando que los campos estén vacíos, si lleno el primero me toma el formulario como valido, y ya no comprueba lo demás

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así:

```
if (user == "" || full == "" || mail == "" || pass == "" || rpas == ""){
        alert("Uno de los campos esta vacio, por favor rellenalo");
        return false;
    }
    if (pass !== rpas){
        alert("Las contraseñas no son iguales");
        return false;
    }
    if (user.length > 28){
        alert("Tu nombre de usuario tiene algun problema");
        return false;
    }
    if (user.length < 6){
        alert("Tu nombre de usuario es muy corto");
        return false;
    }
    if (pass.length < 8 || pass.length > 25){
        alert("Contraseña muy corta o muy larga");
        return false;
    }
    if (mail.length < 9 || mail.length > 40){
        alert("Correo es muy corto o muy largo");
        return false;
    }
    if (!expresion.test(mail)){
        alert("Formato de correo no valido o el campo esta vacio");
        return false;
    }
    if (full.length < 5 || full.length > 30){
        alert("Nombre completo muy corto o muy largo");
        return false;
    }

    //Si todo apsa, retorno Verdadero
    return true;
```

No requieres de tantos else if, por otro lado, también realice cambios en alguna validaciones en las cuales redundabas con lo mismo luego.

Comment: no funciona, lo coloque en esta web study-is-of-all.rf.gd ve a registro y prueba, le falta estilo, y el archivo de registro no esta completo, y vas a ver que no funciona, ya tiene el código que colocaste arriba.

Comment: te indico que vi el código y también el js que agregaste, pues pasa que olvidaste cerrar la ultima llave de tu archivo de validación js, y como lo estas cargando como método externo, debes utilizar Ctrl+f5 para limpiar la cache y que se carguen correctamente, hazlo y cuéntanos de nuevo, ve tu codigo funcionando aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/xfxstudios/bq7em7cp/

Comment: ya funciona, muchas gracias

Comment: recuerda colocar la respuesta como solución para que otros la tengan como referencia. Saludos